# CSS backdrop-filter on SVG elements

Tags: css, svg, blur, css-filters

I am trying to add a [backdrop filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) to a SVG `<rect>` which lies on top of another SVG `<rect>`.

However, the CSS properties `backdrop-filter: blur(10px)` and `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px)` do not seem to have any effect on SVG elements. When I do the same for two `<div>` it works.

How can I achieve the same effect for the two `<rect>`?

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.outerrect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 120px;
}

.innerrect {
  position: absolute;
  
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.outerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 140px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid;
  
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect class="outerrect" fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100"></rect>
  <rect class="innerrect" x="140" y="20" width="120" height="60"></rect>
</svg>
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the MDN page you have referenced: `Applies to: all elements; In SVG, it applies to container elements excluding the <defs> element and all graphics elements`

Comment: So to put it in other words it is not possible to achieve what I want? Or do I have to use groups and apply it to them?

Comment: It may be a good idea to play around with groups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that the Filter effects module is very much experimental and not that widely implemented (newest Edge and Chrome behind a flag), the best you could do is go back to SVG 1.1 filters. The following technique looks pretty innocuous, but still Firefox has problems at the border of the backdrop content:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="200">
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <rect id="rect" x="140" y="20" width="120" height="100" />
  </clipPath>
  <filter id="blur" width="160%" height="160%" x="-30%" y="-30%">
    <!-- insert a neutral background color to prevent the backdrop showing
         through blurred regions with alpa < 1 -->
    <feFlood flood-color="#fff" result="neutral"/>
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blurred" />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="neutral" />
      <feMergeNode in="blurred" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <!-- group everything you want to include in the backdrop -->
  <g id="backdrop">
    <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" />
    <rect fill="yellow" x="120" y="40" width="40" height="40" />
  </g>
  <!-- make sure the clip-path is applied after the filter -->
  <g style="clip-path: url(#clip)">
    <use xlink:href="#backdrop" style="filter: url(#blur)" />
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" style="fill:none;stroke:black" />
</svg>
```

As long as you stay over regions far enough inside the backdrop image and without alpha values to consider, a shorter version will work:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200">
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <rect id="rect" x="140" y="20" width="120" height="100" />
  </clipPath>
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blurred" />
  </filter>
  <image id="backdrop" width="400" height="200" href="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
  <g style="clip-path: url(#clip);">
    <use id="overlay" xlink:href="#backdrop" style="filter: url(#blur);" />
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" style="fill:none;stroke:black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works well. However it still looks a bit like a workaround. I hope there will be developed better solutions for this problem in the future.

Comment: For example I think there is still no way to have multiple layers of these blurred layers stacked on top of each other like I would like to have for my visualisation: https://pasteboard.co/HcYhYyX.png
But for the moment, I am happy ... ;)